# Visual Studio RSS Subscription not working

Tags: windows-xp, rss, visual-studio-2008, blogging, google-code

I'm trying to set a new RSS feed in Visual Studio. I had changed it from the default to the Silverlight blog and now I'm trying to change it to the Google Code blog. Only thing is that it wont load the feed for Google code. I expect it wants XML or close, With MS lax support of standards I figured it would probably except web pages with links to RSS feeds. Any way, I digress.

The link I'm using is:
http://feeds.feedburner.com/blogspot/Dcni?format=xml

dose it want to see an URL ending in .xml?

Thanks,

Comment: I think you may have better luck asking this on Stack Overflow. Much greater percentage of VS users there.

Comment: But this isn't really a programming related question, SU is probably the right place for it.

Comment: @heavyd - No, I'm not complaining or anything. Far from it. I'm just saying, that due to higher number of VS users there, he may be able to get better answers. If he wants to keep it here, fine by me.

Comment: @Idigas, understood.  I'm just pointing out that the SO users would likely see this question and move it here anyway, even though many of them are heavy VS users, solely because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @heavyd - fair enough :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick bit of research, it appears that Visual Studio doesn't support [Atom Feeds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29).  The feeds that you setup must be in the [RSS format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS).

Comment: Do you know of a way to check this or a service that converts them?

Comment: I check just by opening the URL in Firefox and select **View->Page Source**.  RSS feeds will have an `<rss>` tag as the root element.  As for converting them, that sounds like an excellent question for the SU community :)

Comment: There are ways to convert it using external software, or here's a site that will do it on their site for you:  http://www.2rss.com/software.php?page=atom2rss